# Ruby method #send

Tags: ruby

The following code uses:

```
send("#{duck1}=", true)
```

and I tried the following code instead and was wondering why it didn't work:

```
duck1.send(=,true)
```

Terminal shows: `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `send` must be a symbol or a string representing a method name. `=` is not a symbol or a string. It is not even an object. Furthermore, even if you do `send(:"=", ...)` or  `send("=", ...)`, it will not work unless you have defined `=` as a method in a non-usual way. (Edited following  Bob Gilmore and Jörg W Mittag's comments)

Comment: So "#{duck1}=" is a method and "=" is not. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. things like `foo=` are valid forms for a method name. Whether such method is defined or not is a different thing. `=` represents assignment, and cannot be a method name.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Really appreciate it. method#send is so powerful yet elusive, and I find the official document not very helpful on explaining how to use it. Thanks again!

Comment: The first argument to `send` can also be a string.

Comment: @BobGilmore Forgot to mention that. Thanks.

Comment: @TiHuan There are several forms of methods that change the appearance when they are put into a method name as a string or a symbol. Methods like `foo=` mentioned here are one example. In usage, they are used with optional spacing like `object.foo = ...`, but as a method name, you don't put a space. Also, for unary operators used like `~object`, their method names are written like `"@~"`. That may have been tricky.

Comment: Perfect! I was thinking about the optional space, but obviously you'd read my mind. Haha. I'll remember "@~". That's really tricky. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: "there is no such method as `=`" – `define_method(:'=') do puts 'Hello' end; send(:'=') # Hello`

Answer (score 2):

Before we even get into the valid argument types for the `send` method, take a look at the error message.  It's telling you that it's a *syntax error* to have a "bare" equals sign immediately after that opening parenthesis. So, right off the bat, you know that something is very wrong.

Now, if you take a closer look at the call that *does* work, you'll see that you're passing the *string* "something=", not a "bare" equals sign.  *That* has a chance of working, based on the types of arguments that `send` takes.

If you read the documentation for `send`, you'll see that the first argument can be either a string or a symbol.  `"#{duck1}="` will be interpolated to be a string, so that's valid.

Now, the question becomes, "what is `duck1`, and will `"#{duck1}="` be interpolated to the name of an *existing* function?  I can't answer that, it completely depends on the value of `duck1`.

Comment: Thank you for your input! So it seems like #send only takes symbol or string and interprets it as a method to do evaluation. And in this case, to get "#{duck1}=" to work, we also need to have attr_accessor :)